# BLE access issue with `Cordova run android --device' command?

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, phonegap

I'm building a simple BLE application using cordona/phonegap.

I use [BLE lock](https://github.com/MakeBluetooth/ble-lock) as an example. Everything works fine with `cordova serve': cordova can scan and access available BLE devices with Phonegap Android application.

[image]
[image]

However, with `cordova run android --device,' I could build a standalone Android app, download the app to my Android device; but no BLE devices are shown when I execute the downloaded app on the Android device.

[image]

What might make this difference? Do I need to do something more to make the standalone app access the Android BLE features?

Comment: Have you added bluetooth and location permissions to your manifest for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [cordova bluetooth plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ble-central) into the Cordova app.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central
```

If you're using the phonegap cli, try

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central
```

The app works when running in the [PhoneGap Developer App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app&hl=en_US) because the bluetooth plugin is pre-installed in that app. When you're running directly in Cordova, you need to install the plugin yourself.

Before you install the plugin, you can see the error using Chrome. To get the stack trace from the application on your Android device: Open Chrome on your computer, enter chrome://inspect, choose your device. You should see a message like this in the console.

[image: stacktrace in chrome dev tools showing ble is not defined]

After you install the plugin and redeploy the project, scanning should work.

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central
 cordova run android --device
```

[image: screenshot of updated android app that found a bluetooth device]

Answer (score 0):

Don's answer is (almost) perfect to me, but I think I need to add some more things just in case.

## plugin installation

The command I actually used was `phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central` from [this site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ble-central).

After that, I have a plugin directory created with BLE libraries.

## modification of config.xml (?)

I don't think this step is not necessary, but [the site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ble-central) says that these two lines should be added in config.xml, but I could build the app without this step.

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-ble-central" source="npm" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.1.0" />`

## execution

I could use this command to build and install the app.

`cordova platform add android`
`cordova run android --device`

## The cause of the problem

When I tried some BLE plugins, I guess I installed other plugins. As a result I have `com.megster.rordova.ble` and `cordova-plugin-ble-central` in my plugins directory. I also guess config.xml and package.json might have some wrong information not to include the correct BLE library.

So, when I clean installed the BLE lock program, and installed the BLE plugin and build the app, everything seems fine.